# How to Check/uncheck dynamic radio buttons in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is asked probably a million times but I can't get this one to work.

I have 3 radio buttons which are created normally. I want to place a 4th radio button between the first and third radio button. When clicking this radio button the third and fourth radio button should appear and unchecking this radio should make them disappear.

To clarify I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/7h4q4wx1/)

So what I tried is below. I created a new div with the radio. Injected it after the first radio. This works ok! When I check the newly created radio the 3rd and 4th appear. So works ok! 
The problem is when I click the first radio, the second keeps checked so the 3rd and 4th radio is are still visible. I thought that it would work with `.prop` or I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Anybody?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var newContainer = $('<div class="gui-spacer"></div><div class="gui-block-option"><div class="gui-field"><div class="gui-radio"><div class="tm-radio"><input type="radio" value="" name="shipment_method_wholesale" id="gui-form-shipping-wholesale" class=""></div><label for="gui-form-shipping-wholesale">Ik wil graag bij mijn groothandel bestellen(Afhalen)</label></div><div class="gui-field-content"><p>text over bestellen bij groothandel</p></div></div></div>');

    $('#gui-form .gui-block-option:not(:first)').hide();
    $('#gui-form-shipping-wholesale').prop('checked', false);
    $('#gui-form .gui-block-option:first').after(newContainer);


    $('input[name="shipment_method_wholesale"]').bind('change', function () {

        var showOrHide = ($(this).val() == 1) ? false : true;
        $('#gui-form .gui-block-option:not(:first) ').toggle(showOrHide);
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: first radio and second should be in a group if you only want one of them checked at a time.

Comment: If you give each radio input the same name then only one can be checked at a time. Your first and third and fourth radios have a name `shipment_method`. Your second has `shipment_method_wholesale`. Change this to `name="shipment_method"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio buttons are grouped by their `name` property.  If you want to ensure that only one can be selected at a time then make sure that they have the same `name`.

All I did to get your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7h4q4wx1/5/) to work was change the `name` of the radio button you were dynamically adding to `shipment_method`.

```
var newContainer = $('<div class="gui-spacer"></div><div class="gui-block-option"><div class="gui-field"><div class="gui-radio"><div class="tm-radio"><input type="radio" value="" name="shipment_method" id="gui-form-shipping-wholesale" class=""></div><label for="gui-form-shipping-wholesale">Ik wil graag bij mijn groothandel bestellen(Afhalen)</label></div><div class="gui-field-content"><p>text over bestellen bij groothandel</p></div></div></div>');
```

Edit: I had to make some other changes to get it hiding and displaying the other buttons correctly

Comment: I'm deeply ashamed :(

Answer (score 0):

To be part of the same group you need to make the "name" attribute the same for all buttons part of that group.